# Apple calendar integration in iOS app?

Tags: objective-c, swift, calendar, event-handling, icalendar

[image]Does anyone integrate iCalendar your application ?

I have to implement calendar with event handling . 
Just same as  --->  https://github.com/jumartin/Calendar

I have tried with many application available on github but cannot finf single application for calendar event handling Just like our Apple Calendar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What events do you want to handle?

Comment: @Anokrize I have added one image for reference.
I have to implement same at application side

Answer (score 1):

Customise start date and end date based on you're requirements this code  will add events to you're iPhone calendar

```
    let dateFormatter2: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mma"
    let date: NSDate = dateFormatter2.dateFromString(startDate)!
    let date2: NSDate = dateFormatter2.dateFromString(EndDate)!



    if (EKEventStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(.Event) != EKAuthorizationStatus.Authorized) {
        eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(.Event, completion: {
            granted, error in
            self.createEvent(eventStore, title: self.HelpEventString, startDate: date , endDate: date2)
        })
    } else {
        createEvent(eventStore, title: "Event created on particular date between start and time interval and end date time interval", startDate: date, endDate: date2)
    }

    func createEvent(eventStore: EKEventStore, title: String, startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate) {
    let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)

    event.title = title
    event.startDate = startDate
    event.endDate = endDate

    event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
    do {
        try eventStore.saveEvent(event, span: .ThisEvent)
        savedEventId = event.eventIdentifier
    } catch {

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you implement calendar functionality with NScalendar or third party tools.

I have to implement Calender UI + Calender event handling .

Comment: JTCalender is implemented in objectivec 

But I am not getting dragEvent from one date to another(in JTCalender).

Comment: I have restrict month display for calendar but cannot get Add Event method for the same

Comment: Hi @Jaswanth Kumar Just for update.  
https://github.com/jumartin/Calendar  
Download Phone-Compatibility version .It works same as our Apple calendar.